# Filter array of arrays using mongodb C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I use [MongoDB.Driver 2.10.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.Driver/2.10.2/)

The problem: I can not create a filter for an array of arrays.

I need 2 filters:

1. by UUID in Car
2. by Name in Measure < Measures < Info

I tried a lot of versions with **Builders<RootEntity>.Filter**, but no luck. LINQ didn't help me too.

Output filter data type is **FilterDefinition<RootEntity>**, because I use other filters.

C# models (I removed and renamed some fields):

```
public class RootEntity
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public IList<List<CarData>> CarsData { get; set; } = new List<List<CarData>>();
}

public class CarData
{
    public Car Car { get; set; }
    public IList<Info> Info { get; set; } = new List<Info>();
}

public class Car
{
    public Guid UUID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Info
{
    public bool Finished { get; set; }
    public IList<InfoMeasure> Measures { get; set; } = new List<InfoMeasure>();
}

public class InfoMeasure
{
    public Measure Measure { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}

public class Measure
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My root model into the DB:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5ef77b35307ab74bc44b890b"
  },
  "UserId": "5ed2c08cb885f33b54fb20a6",
  "Cars": [
    [
      {
        "Car": {
          "UUID": "9b436f56-a423-40e4-a21a-d7954a04fa58",
          "Name": "...."
        },
        "Info": [
          {
            "Finished": false,
            "Measures": [
              {
                "Measure": {
                  "Name": "Weight (kg)"
                },
                "Value": 40
              },
              {
                "Measure": {
                  "Name": "Length (cm)"
                },
                "Value": 4400
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you filter a list of documents, what you get back is a `RootEntity` based on the filter

```
Builders<RootEntity>.Filter(_ => _.CarsData.Where(x => x.Car.UUID.Equals("SOMETHING").Count() > 0)
```

But when you talk about filtering the Info.Measures.Measure... that wont work. Now you are talking about modifying the RootEntity by removing the data from the result you get with the above Filter. You can retrieve the RootEntity based on Car.UUID but not modify the Info items.